# PHP Bash error suppresion

Tags: bash, php

I'm using a PHP script from cli, the script calls `exec()` a few times. There are some minor errors sometimes, which are handled by the PHP script. I'm suppressing the errors by appending `2>/dev/null` to the end of each command...

Is there any way to achieve that without adding the aforementioned?

Comment: Well, what are the errors? You could handle the errors in your `php` script so they don't appear at all.

Answer (score 2):

Not with `exec()`. You'd have to use [`proc_open()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) if you want to capture/suppress stderr.